# How to get List from Object in Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, arraylist

How to get List from Object? Below you can find my code:

```
ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity("localhost:8083/connectors/", Object.class);
Object object = responseEntity.getBody();
```

Actually object variable is a List of Objects(Strings) and I need to get all these Strings.

If I print it out `System.out.println(object.toString());` it looks like that:

```
[objvar, values, test, object, servar, larms, aggregates, sink, records]
```

I need to get List of these Strings to dynamic use it. Could you please help?

Comment: In place of Object using List

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this out. This should work.

```
ResponseEntity<String[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity("localhost:8083/connectors/", String[].class);
List<String> object = Arrays.asList(responseEntity.getBody());
```

For simple cases the code above works, but when you have complex json structures which you want to map, then it is ideal to use ParameterizedTypeReference.

```
ResponseEntity<List<String>> responseEntity =
        restTemplate.exchange("localhost:8083/connectors/",
            HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {
            });
List<String> listOfString = responseEntity.getBody();
```

Comment: If I use ResponseEntity<List<String>> there is an issue `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ResponseEntity<List> to ResponseEntity<List<String>>` I can put List of String instead but then `List is a raw type. References to generic type List<E> should be parameterized` and also in the second line `Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<String>`

Comment: About the first way, you use a raw type. How can you retrieve a `List<String>` then as `getBody()` is invoked ? I generally use the second way.

Comment: @Tom I think that the first way is not valid. Use rather the second one.

Comment: @davidxxx, thanks for pointing it out. Tom I have updated my answer. check it out.

Comment: @pvpkiran Much better. And very good alternative with `ParameterizedTypeReference`. You have of course my vote :)

Comment: @pvpkiran and what if my JSON is much more complicated and looks like that: `{
    "name": "objvar-current-alarms-history-cassandra-sink",
    "connector": {
        "state": "RUNNING",
        "worker_id": "10.10.117.172:8083"
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "state": "RUNNING",
            "id": 0,
            "worker_id": "10.10.117.172:8083"
        },
        {
            "state": "RUNNING",
            "id": 1,
            "worker_id": "10.10.117.172:8083"
        }
    ]
}` I need only to check if status is running or failed

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that this object will always be a `List`, just cast it

```
List<?> lst= (List) responseEntity.getBody();
```

However, you can't directly cast it as a `List<String>`, so you'll have to check the elements type by a loop or a stream to produce a typed list.
Any way that the used API can return the actual type?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as a workaround

```
List list = java.util.Arrays.asList(object.toString());
```

Alternatively you can use Libraries like 
[ObjectMapper](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial),
Which directly converts the json strings to your desired model

Answer (score 0):

Following the code if goes for authorizing with jwt & then want to retrieve a list:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        
        // set `content-type` header
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        
        // request body parameters
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("email", "abc@email.com");
        map.put("password", "pass123");
        

        // build the request
        HttpEntity<Map<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

        // send POST request
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/user/login", entity, String.class);


        HttpHeaders myHeader = new HttpHeaders();
        

        myHeader.add("User-Agent", "Spring's RestTemplate" );
        myHeader.set("Authorization","Bearer "+response.getBody());
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(myHeader);
        
    
        ResponseEntity<Product[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/secure/products", HttpMethod.GET, request, Product[].class);
        List<Product> object = Arrays.asList(responseEntity.getBody());
        
        System.out.println(object);
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work for you:

```
ResponseEntity<Object[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity("localhost:8083/connectors/", Object[].class);
List<Object> responseList = Arrays.asList(responseEntity.getBody());
```

(Same goes for List[] instead of Object[])

Comment: Unfortunately not `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ResponseEntity<Object> to ResponseEntity<Object[]>`

Comment: @tom, did you added also Object[]?